# Should you communicate the number of Doors required?

Tags: gm-techniques, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

In World of Darkness 2.0, there is the Social Maneuvering system, it requires you to calculate a number of "Doors" (p192) that must be opened with a character to accomplish a task.

> Once you’ve declared your character’s goal, the next step is
> to determine the scope of the challenge. We represent this with
> “Doors,” which reflect a character’s resistance to coercion: her
> social walls, his skepticism, mistrust, or just a hesitance toward intimacy. It’s abstract and means different things in every given case.

**After calculating the number of Doors, should I communicate the number to the players?**

I'm not taking the sample in the book as a yes, because those never really mention communication, so much as what each person does.

The way I'm looking at it is, on one side, the Player Character probably has no idea how hard it'll be, on the other side maybe it's frustrating for Players not to know, also maybe there are other things I'm not considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no more than you would reveal, for free, how many dots the NPC has in Composure or any other mechanical number.

Comment: You often do reveal that, though; it's common to have a social roll resisted by the opponent's Resolve or Composure, which will take a particular number of dice out of the actor's pool.

Comment: @Jadasc Yeah, that's why "no more than..." and "for free". It's "no", unless something causes it to be revealed, or the PCs have the ability to discover it. There's nothing special about this number, compared to all other numbers, that would make it a free disclosure. Pro-metagaming playstyles aside, of course.

Comment: interestingly of course the number of doors may or may not be equal to the resolve or composure since that's just the base starting point...